# AttributeError: 'Win32EventLoop' object has no attribute '_next_idle_time'

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm doing OpenGL in python and I switch my context from glut to pyglet because glut doesn't have a close window event. When I did the window only updates when I move the mouse over it. The Documentation says the draw function will be called after all the events are pulled. I'm guessing it won't because of this error.

```
AttributeError: 'Win32EventLoop' object has no attribute '_next_idle_time'
```

I got it to draw but there's several problems. I had to schedule a function to the pyglet clock that is empty to be called 1/60 times and it updates. But since it's drawing after it receives any events. If I move the mouse over it the cpu usage goes from 3-4 to a full core, 25%. (I have a quad-core). My guess is it is drawing more than 60 frames when I move the mouse over it. If this is a windows 7 problem I'll have to go back to glut.